# Force SQL to create certain number of Divs in generator

Tags: html, sql

I am busy working on a SQL generator that auto populates a form when certain paramaters are input. Data gets generated from Select Stored Procedures

I am trying however to force SQL to always create a certain number of divs regardless of how many paramaters come through.

In my scenario I always want 4 div tags to be created, just being empty if theres no data available to create 4

My current code setup looks like this

```
    SELECT @Control = '<div><input type=' 
        SELECT @Control = @Control  + '"text" name="' + @Parameter          
                                    + '" maxlength="' + Isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Max), 100) +'"'        
        IF @GenType = 'READONLY'
            SELECT @Control = @Control + ' disabled="disabled"'
        ELSE
            SELECT @Control = @Control + + ' required'           

        INSERT INTO #html VALUES ('             <div class="row">')        
        INSERT INTO #html VALUES ('                                   <div><label for="' + @Parameter + '">' + @Name + ':' + '</label></div>')                
        INSERT INTO #html VALUES ('                                   ' + @Control + '/></div>') 
        INSERT INTO #html VALUES ('                             </div>')
```

Current results

```
    <div class="row">
               <div><label for="AsAt">As At:</label></div>
               <div><input type="text" name="AsAt" maxlength="50" disabled="disabled"/></div>
           </div>
```

Expected Results

```
    <div class="row">
               <div><label for="AsAt">As At:</label></div>
               <div><input type="text" name="AsAt" maxlength="50"    disabled="disabled"/></div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div></div>
```

As you can see from above results, In current results my paramaters brought back two results. However I ALWAYS want 4 div results to be brought back, so if only two (as in this case) divs come back. I want it to post with 2 blank divs to equal 4 divs within the row.

Comment: what is the output of your code and what output you expect?

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: It think you should both to your question to make it answerable

Comment: @Bulat Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my original question and cut it from the comments to make easier to read